# Too many Bytes Using Ultrasonic Sensors

Tags: sensors, i2c, wire-library

I need to send one transmission and record multiple distances with 4 receivers, but everytime I use more than 2 receivers, the serial data does not print. What can I do?

P.S. I'm using 5 SRF-02 Sensors, 1 transmitter and 4 receivers all via I2C.

```c
#include <Wire.h>

#define cmdByte 0x00                                 // Command byte
#define rangeByte 0x02                             // Byte for start of ranging data

byte highByte = 0x00;                                // Stores high byte from ranging
byte lowByte = 0x00;                                // Stored low byte from ranging
int range = 0; 
int rangeData;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();  
}

void loop() {
   D0_1= getRange(0x70, 0x71);  
   Serial.println(D0_1);
   D0_2= getRange(0x70, 0x72);  
   Serial.println(D0_2);
   D0_3= getRange(0x70, 0x73);  
   Serial.println(D0_3);
   D0_4= getRange(0x70, 0x74);  
   Serial.println(D0_4);
}

 int getRange (uint8_t send_address, uint8_t rec_address)
 {
  Wire.beginTransmission(rec_address);
  Wire.write((uint8_t)cmdByte);
  Wire.write((uint8_t)0x56);
  Wire.endTransmission(); 

  Wire.beginTransmission(send_address);             // Start communticating with SRF02
  Wire.write((uint8_t)cmdByte);                         // Send Command Byte
  Wire.write((uint8_t)0x5C);        // Transmit an 8 cycle 40khz burst - no ranging takes place
  Wire.endTransmission();  

  delay(80);                                                           // Wait for ranging to be complete

  Wire.beginTransmission(rec_address);       // start communicating with SRFmodule
  Wire.write((uint8_t)rangeByte);                 // Call the register for start of ranging data
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.requestFrom(rec_address, 2);            // Request 2 bytes from SRF module

  while(Wire.available() < 2);                    // Wait for data to arrive
  highByte = Wire.read();                           // Get high byte
  lowByte = Wire.read();                           // Get low byte

  range = (highByte << 8 ) + lowByte;              // Put them together


 delay(120); 


 return(range);                                                    // Returns Range
 }
```

Comment: My magic crystal ball tells me that.... You didn't even say what ultrasonic sensor you are using!

Comment: Whoops, my apologies, I'm using SRF-02 sensors.

Comment: Now it's easier ;) Did you check the addresses on the bus? Check also the LEDS (see [here for the led coding](http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/srf02techI2C.htm)). And... Can you timeout when the I2C does not reply? Check with the main library or try to use a software one which does timeout...

Comment: the LEDS don't blink if I try to use more than 3 receivers.

Comment: @Umbus your code doesn't compile. Missing declarations of D0_x variables. Also did you changed the addresses of 4 sensors to 0xE2, 0xE4, 0xE6, 0xE8 and tested every single one alone? Did they respond correctly?

Comment: If the leds blink when you put 2 of them and don't if you put 3, then the prblem is 1) the power supply or 2) the pullups on the I2C. You put only two resistors (one on SCL and one on SDA) right?

Comment: i dont use resistors

Comment: @Personagem it compiles on my computer with a slight error and will run, and all the sensors have the right address, I've checked the blinking lights